# Getting Error: index.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: javascript, json, express, axios, ejs

Basically, I'm creating an express server using this public API: `https://bored-api.appbrewery.com/random` to make a request from it that every time when a user set the 2 dropdowns and click on the button, he/she gets a specific activity, type of activity and how much people can participants in this kind of activity.
However, I'm getting this error: "index.ejs while compiling ejs" every time that I try to load my express server.
I tried to identify any errors in the embedded HTML codes, but I couldn't find them.
It would be very helpful if somebody could find the error.

**index.js:**

```js
import express from "express";
import bodyParser from "body-parser";
import axios from "axios";

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const response = await axios.get("https://bored-api.appbrewery.com/random");
    const result = response.data;
    res.render("index.ejs", { data: result });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Failed to make request:", error.message);
    res.render("index.ejs", {
      error: error.message,
    });
  }
});

app.post("/", async (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  try {
const type = req.body.type;
const participants = req.body.participants;
const response = await axios.get( `https://bored-api.appbrewery.com/filter?type=${type}&participants=${participants}`);
  const result = response.data;
  console.log(result);
  res.render("index.ejs", {
    data: result[Math.floor(Math.random() * result.length)],
  });
} catch (error) {
console.error("Failed to make request:", error.message);
res.render("index.ejs", {
  error: "No activities that match your criteria.",
});
}

});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server running on port: ${port}`);
});

**index.ejs:**
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/styles/main.css">
  <title>I'm Bored</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="container">
    <h1>Let's find something for you to do ✌️</h1>

    <form action="/" id="form" class="form" method="POST">
      <select name="type" class="form-select">
        <option value="" data-display="Select">Random type</option>
        <option value="education">Education</option>
        <option value="charity">Charity</option>
        <option value="recreational">Recreational</option>
        <option value="relaxation">Relaxation</option>
        <option value="busywork">Busywork</option>
        <option value="social">Social</option>
        <option value="diy">DIY</option>
        <option value="music">Music</option>
      </select>
      <select name="participants" class="form-select">
        <option value="">Any number of people</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
        <option value="4">4</option>
      </select>
      <button type="submit" class="form-submit">Go</button>
    </form>
    <section id="cards" class="cards">
      <%if (locals.data) {%>

        <article class="card-item">
          <h2 class="card-activity">
            <%=data.activity %>
          </h2>
          <div class="card-info">
            <span class="card-type">
              <%=data.type%>
            </span>
            <span class="card-participants">
              participants: <%= data.participants%>
                <span class="card-number"></span>
            </span>
          </div>
        </article>

        <% } %>


          <%if (locals.error) {%>
            <div id="tag-error" class="tag-error">
              <%=error%>
            </div>
            <%}%>
    </section>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Error Message Screenshot:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCOjm.png)